# How would you go about finding the area probability?

Tags: area

*A triangle is formed inside a square by joining corner C with the mid points of sides AD and AB. If a point in the square is chosen randomly, what is the probability that the point will be inside the triangle as well?*

[image: bou]

The answer is 37.5%. However, I am unsure of how to arrive at that answer. I calculated the following areas for the unshaded triangles but I don't know what steps to take afterwards:

area of 2 big triangles = $[(s/2)^2 * (1/2)]$× 2 big triangles→  $s^2/4 $

area of 1 small triangle = $[(s/2)^2 * (1/2)]$ ×1 small triangle→ $s^2/8$

Total area of unshaded triangles = $s^2/4+s^2/8=(3s^2)/8$

Comment: $\frac58$ of the square is unshaded.  Your small triangle calculation should be $\frac{s^2}8$.

Comment: area of 1 small triangle = $b * h * (1/2)$ = $[(s/2)^2 * (1/2)]$ × 1 small triangle→ $s^2/4$. I'm not sure how you got $s^2/8$...

Comment: Try again, I promise you've made an arithmetic mistake.  Alternatively, you should be able to eyeball the area to be an eighth of the square in the diagram.

Comment: Caught the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing to note here is that your area for the two big triangles (lets call them $A_1, A_2$) and the small triangle (call it $A_3$) is wrong... 
The area for the a triangle is simple base multiplied by height multiplied by 0.5. 
If you look carefully, one of the sides (for the big triangle) is $\frac{s}{2}$ while the other is $s$, hence the area is:
$$
A_1 = A_2 = \frac{s}{2}\cdot s\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{s^2}{4}
$$
The base and height of the small triangle is $\frac{s}{2}$ each. Hence, its area is: 
$$
A_3 = \frac{s}{2}\cdot\frac{s}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{s^2}{8}
$$
Hence total area covered by non-shaded area is:
$$
A_1 + A_2 + A_3 = \frac{s^2}{4} + \frac{s^2}{4}+ \frac{s^2}{8} = \frac{5s^2}{8}
$$
we know area covered by shaded part = Area of square - area covered by non-shaded part:
$$
s^2 - \frac{5s^2}{8} = \frac{3s^2}{8} = 0.375\cdot s^2
$$
Probability of landing in shaded part = $\frac{\text{area of shaded part}}{\text{total area}}$
$$
\therefore P = \frac{0.375s^2}{s^2} = 0.375 = 37.5\%
$$

Comment: Very thorough explanation. Thank you very much! :)